# Calculated Pandas dataframe column for a key, based on the value of a key

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

In pandas/Python, for every row where question_id = 3 and selected_reponse = 'Tertiary/University Postgraduate', I want to populate a new column called 'Tertiary' with either 'Yes' or 'No', for each user_id.

Not sure of the best way to do this. Any help would be most appreciated.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is not necessary set values per `user_id`, so use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask:

```
mask = (df.question_id == 3) & (df.selected_reponse == 'Tertiary/University Postgraduate')

df['Tertiary'] = np.where(mask, 'Yes', 'No')
```

But if need set `Yes` to all rows per group if match `mask` use:

```
df['Tertiary'] = np.where(mask.groupby(df['user_id']).transform('any'), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: so simple - I can't believe I missed the grouping. Thanks!